# Visual Basic 4: Expected Array

Tags: vb6

I've been trying to do a little project on Visual Basic 4 (I know, old version. But it needs to work with old computers so), and I have this code for a calculator. It's for the equals command:

```vb
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    Dim sd As Integer
    Dim operator As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim Val As String

    If operator = 1 Then
        result = Val(num) + Val(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    ElseIf operator = 2 Then
        result = Val(num) - Val(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    ElseIf operator = 3 Then
        result = Val(num) * Val(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    ElseIf operator = 4 Then
        result = Val(num) / Val(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    ElseIf operator = 5 Then
        result = Val(num) Mod Val(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    ElseIf operator = 6 Then
        result = Val(num) * Val(num)
        txtOutput.Text = result
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, once I run it, it shows this error:
[image: Problem].

I tried searching on the Internet, and the only solution I have found online is to "Close and reopen Visual Basic and hope it works", but it doesn't... Any suggestions?

Comment: You have declared Val as string: `Dim Val As String`. Why?

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the problem that's directly causing the error is the `Dim Val as String` statement, but I don't see where anyone has mentioned the *reason*...

The issue is that by `Dim`ing the identifier `Val`, you've effectively masked the intrinsic `Val()` function.  Later in your original code, when you refer to the identifier, you're doing so using a syntax that requires either an array or a function; since you've `Dim`ed it as a variable, the parser then assumes that it must be an array variable, which it's not - hence the `Expected array` error.

Simple fix - just delete the `Dim Val as String` line.  The code could be shortened somewhat by moving the `txtOutput.Text = result` statement outside of the `If`...`End If` block, which would be an improvement in both size and clarity (but not performance), but it would otherwise work as is.

Answer (score 2):

As @Steeeve says, remove the 'Val as String' line, but I suspect that the error is actually appearing because all the lines starting 'result' have two statements on the line and that's confusing VB. You only need

```
txtOutput.Text = result
```

once after the If ... End If statement:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    
    Dim sd As Integer
    Dim operator As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    
    If operator = 1 Then
      result = Val(num) + Val(txtOutput.Text)
    
    ElseIf operator = 2 Then
      result = Val(num) - Val(txtOutput.Text)
    
    ElseIf operator = 3 Then
      result = Val(num) * Val(txtOutput.Text)
    
    ElseIf operator = 4 Then
      result = Val(num) / Val(txtOutput.Text)
    
    ElseIf operator = 5 Then
      result = Val(num) Mod Val(txtOutput.Text)
    
    ElseIf operator = 6 Then
      result = Val(num) * Val(num)
    
    End If
    
    txtOutput.Text = result
 End Sub
```

Comment: Not to critique your solution, but where do you see multiple statements on one line? In my browser their code is correctly formatted (if non-optimal)

Comment: The original posting was edited and reformatted after I posted my answer. Originally the lines just had a space after the 'result' statement and were immediately followed on the same line by the txtOutput.txt lines.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem is the redefining Val, but you can also clean things up a bit to make it easier to understand by doing the conversions just once.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    Dim sd As Integer
    Dim operator As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
   
    Dim vNum = Val(num)
    Dim vOuput = Val(txtOutput.Text)

    If operator = 1 Then
        result = vNum + vOuput
    ElseIf operator = 2 Then
        result = vNum - vOuput
    ElseIf operator = 3 Then
        result = vNum * vOuput
    ElseIf operator = 4 Then
        result = vNum / vOuput
    ElseIf operator = 5 Then
        result = vNum Mod vOuput
    ElseIf operator = 6 Then
        result = vNum * vNum  
    End If
   
    txtOutput.Text = result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*Val* is a built-in function which returns a number read from a string.

Example:

value% = Val("abc123") 'returns 123